# Python Print Trailing Comma Behavior using sys.stdout

Tags: python, stdout

When printing in Python (2.x), you can add a trailing comma to suppress the newline like so:

```
print "This will be first ",
print "and this will be on the same line."
```

Is there a way to do this in `sys.stdout`? Something like:

```
sys.stdout("This will be first ", please_dont=True)
sys.stdout("and this will be on the same line.")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sys.stdout.write` doesn't add new line automatically, you don't need extra options:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write("This will be first ")
sys.stdout.write("and this will be on the same line.")
```

Output: `This will be first and this will be on the same line.`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sys.stdout.write("This will be first ") 
sys.stdout.write("and this will be on the same line.\n")   
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: So a flush between the two `write`s is the mechanism behind the newline, correct?

Comment: @Randy: No, but a `sys.stdout.flush()` call may be necessary after `sys.stdout.write(s)` if `s` _doesn't_ contain a newline in order to force the terminal to display the data. I said "may" above because the exact behaviour depends on the terminal. Try this (properly indented), with & without the `flush`: `import sys, time` `for i in range(20):` `sys.stdout.write(' %d ' % i);sys.stdout.flush();time.sleep(1)`

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks. I had written a progress bar in Python, and it's like this example. So `sys.stdout.flush()` will force display the output, but without this, sometimes the terminal will still display the output and it depends on the terminal. That is? :)

Comment: Correct. Some terminals may immediately display whatever you write to stdout, no flushing required, but to make the code portable assume that you do need to flush if there's no newline. FWIW, if you write to stderr instead of stdout you probably won't need to flush, but it's still a good idea to flush, just to make sure it works properly on every terminal.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks, I understand :)